# Getting a value of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, return-value

I have this array which I would like to get the individual values of each item:

This is the result of `print_r($theme_option):`

```
Array ( [side_bars] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Left Page Sidebar [sort] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [title] => Right Page Sidebar [sort] => ) [2] => Array ( [title] => Left Blog Sidebar [sort] => ) [3] => Array ( [title] => Right Blog Sidebar [sort] => ) )
```

I can get at a single sidebar name by using:

```
$theme_option['side_bars'][0]['title'];
```

I tried to loop through and get the individual sidebars using this code but it doesn't return as expected.

```
global $theme_option; 

    if(isset($theme_option['side_bars']) && is_array($theme_option['side_bars'])){
        foreach ($theme_option['side_bars'] as $key => $value) {
            $theme_side_bars["$key"] = "$value";
        }
    }
```

What I ant to try and do is get the value of each "Sidebar" and place the "title" into a dropdown box.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an array `side_bars` which contains an array with all the special infos.

With this code you should have an array with all titles stored in the variable `$theme_side_bars`.

```
global $theme_option; 
$theme_side_bars = array();
if(isset($theme_option['side_bars']) && is_array($theme_option['side_bars'])){
    foreach ($theme_option['side_bars'] as $index=>$arr) {
        $theme_side_bars[] = $arr['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and assistance